# Android ListView scroll is slow

Tags: android

I got a list view that shows a standard image text items, I use the standard ArrayAdapter to work with the view.

My problem is that the scrolling get stuck and not very smooth.

I done some profiling, and found that most of the time a Measure operation is in progress(for many controls most of them are containers)

Is it possible to make stuff work faster? where to start?

Comment: If you're working on an emulator and it's slow that's ok, it will be fine on a real device.

Comment: Its slow on a real sgs2!

Answer (score 4):

Here is very nice presentation about ListView performance http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

Edit: This article may also help http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1/